# Java 8 generate stream of integer based on last value

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I need to generate stream of **integers** that each value is based on the value before according to some math function.

For example - lets say I want to take last number and add 10:
[1, 11, 21, 31, 41, ...]

of course the real function is much more complex.

I tried taking the fibonaci example but couldn't make it work:

```
Stream.iterate(new long[]{ 1, 1 }, p->new long[]{ p[1], p[0]+p[1] })
      .limit(92).forEach(p->System.out.println(p[0]));
```

I can only start at 1.

This is what I tried doing:

```
Stream.iterate(new long[]{ 1 }, p-> {p[0], p[0] + 10})
.limit(4).forEach(p->System.out.println(p[0]));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can only start at 1"?  Also, if you only need the last number to make the next one, you don't need an array:  LongStream.iterate(1, x -> x + 10)...

Comment: The way you're doing it you're building a stream of arrays. I guess this is not what you want to do. If you build a stream of longs with iterate, you can only use the last number to compute the next one, i.e. you can't refer to the number before the last one which is required for fibonacci

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`Stream#iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) method docs:

> Returns an infinite sequential ordered Stream produced by iterative application of a function f to an initial element seed, producing a Stream consisting of seed, f(seed), f(f(seed)), etc.
>
> The first element (position 0) in the Stream will be the provided seed. For n > 0, the element at position n, will be the result of applying the function f to the element at position n - 1.

So, for your example, it should work as follows:

```
Stream.iterate(1L, x -> x + 10L)
    .limit(4)
    .forEach(System.out::println); // 1 11 21 31
```

If your function is too complex, you can abstract it to a method:

```
private long complexFunction(long value) {
    return <very_complex_calculation with value>;
}

long N = 4L;

Stream.iterate(1L, this::complexFunction)
    .limit(N)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

if I don't misunderstand you, you want something like this, you needn't any `long[]`array at all.

```
LongStream.iterate(1, it -> it + 10).limit(8).forEach(System.out::println);
```

for the `Integer`s you can using `IntStream#interate` instead:

```
//                         v--- call your math function here
IntStream.iterate(1, it -> math(it, ...)).limit(8).forEach(System.out::println);
```

**OR** using `LongStream#range` instead:

```
LongStream.range(0,8).map(it -> 10*it + 1).forEach(System.out::println);
```

### Output

```
[1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) to keep another variable when iterating. For the Fibonacci sequence where you would keep the largest of the 2 numbers and in the AtomicLong and the iteration variable would be the smallest. E.g.

```
AtomicLong fibonacci = new AtomicLong(1);
Stream.iterate(1L, x -> fibonacci.getAndAdd(x))
    .limit(10)
    .forEach(i -> System.out.println(fibonacci.get()));
```

Comment: Hi, the OP's fibonacci function is no problem. I also misunderstand it at the first time. he want do something like as fibonacci function.

Comment: OP says he wants a stream where each value is based on the value before. He provided the "add a constant to previous" value as a simple example where the actual function is more complex. I provided a generic solution that can handle fibonacci as well as other complicated sequences.

Comment: well, the `Stream.iterate(...)` is enough for him, sir. no need an additional `AtomicLong`